# How to remove a certain text from a String in Angular, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I created a simple encrypt generator, the user have to type a text to be encrypted and the public key he wants to use to encrypt his text. usually the public key comes with a -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- or -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and it ends with a -----END PUBLIC KEY-----. This is a problem for me, because i only want the key and remove this prefix and the "end public key" in the end of the key. What i want to know, is how can i remove the prefix and the end text from this string variable using Typescript in angular.

the method i use to encrypt is this

```
  public set(data, publicKey){
    let encrypt = new JsEncryptModule.JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
    return encrypt.encrypt(data); 
    }
```

and the method i use to capture the users inputs is this:

```
    this.encryptService.init().then(() => {
        let result = this.encryptService.set(
            this.encryptDataForm.get("textToEncrypt").value,
            this.encryptDataForm.get("secretKey").value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is `string.replace()`

```
public set(data, publicKey){
    let encrypt = new JsEncryptModule.JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----","").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",""));
    return encrypt.encrypt(data); 
}
```

Comment: @Caio Sheperd you're welcome :). when you get a correct, working solution for your question, you should mark it by clicking on the **V sign at the top left** of the answer. when you see a helpful question/answer in general, you should click on the **up arrow at the top left**, to mark that it was helpful. note: you might need specific amount of reputation in order to make some actions like **upvote**